# How Can Add CheckBox Column in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, api, checkbox, datagridview

I Have An API And That API Give Me A Jason Of Some Lists And I Show That In My DataGridView I Want To Set A Check Box Column To My DataGridView For Selecting A Row Of A DataGridView Easier.

That's My Answer From API And Set To DataGridView

```
var WorkListFromApis = serializer.Deserialize<List<Sysmexxp300WorkListFromApi>>(json.ToString());
                    dgv_tests.DataSource = WorkListFromApis;
```

That's My Sysmexxp300WorkListFromApi Class

```
 public class Sysmexxp300WorkListFromApi  //Model For WorkList OF Sysmex Xp300
    {
        public Int64 Id_ReceptionDetail { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public string MasterPriorityName { get; set; }
        public string DetailPriorityName { get; set; }
        public int Code_Patient { get; set; }
        public string CustomCode { get; set; }
        public string WBC { get; set; }
        public string RBC { get; set; }
        public string HGB { get; set; }
        public string HCT { get; set; }

    }
```

How Can I Add Check Box To Each Row ??

Comment: Add a `bool` property to the class.

Comment: @Jimi I don't want to do that i want a dynamic check box column i have so many classes

Comment: Then build a new `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` and add it to the grid's `Columns` collection, specifying its visual position and a name (it may be useful to get the Column by name when needed).

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to add a column with checkboxes:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "X";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";
checkColumn.Width = 50; // or any other value as you wish
checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
checkColumn.FillWeight = 10;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);
```

You also may need to asign `TrueValue` & `FalseValue` to it:

```
checkColumn.FalseValue = "0";
checkColumn.TrueValue = "1";
```

To use `DataGridViewColumn.DisplayIndex` Property
[Check this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

For more and deep information, this may help you [How to make a Checkbox with text cell in a datagridview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/210228/how-to-make-a-checkbox-with-text-cell-in-a-datagri.html)

Comment: Add a reference to the `DisplayIndex` Property.